# Confused when reviewing code from a book

Tags: assembly

Here is a piece of code from a book:

```
.data
count = 100
array WORD count DUP(?)
.code
push OFFSET array
push COUNT
call ArrayFill

ArrayFill PROC
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    pushad
    mov  esi, [ebp+12]
    mov  ecx, [ebp+8]
    cmp  ecx, 0
    je   L2
L1:
    mov  ecx, 1000h          ; generate a random number within 0~FFFFh
    call RandomRange         ; comes from the book's lib
    mov  [esi], ax
    add  esi, TYPE WORD
    loop L1
L2: popad
    pop ebp
    ret 8
ArrayFill ENDP
```

I have two questions against the code above,
1) Since there are `pushad` and `popad`, is it really necessary to write `push ebp` and `pop ebp`?

2) Right below the `L1` label, don't we need to save and restore `ecx` before and after
`mov  ecx, 1000h`
`call RandomRange`?

Comment: Ad 2: why are you thinking that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need the correct value of `ebp` to access to the arguments (`ebp+xx`). The value of ebp is determined by a certain value of `esp` (`push ebp; mov  ebp, esp`). After the `pushad` the value of `esp` is changed so you have to adjust the xx-addition of `ebp+xx`. Do you want to do this? Later you want to let MASM automagically do the job (ARG-directive) but MASM just inserts the same instructions.

2) In the example of your book (Irvine's assembly book I assume) is written:
 *"mov eax,10000h ; get random 0 - FFFFh"*.
 **EAX**! Not ECX! You can't change registers without knowing what you do. If `RandomRange` doesn't change ECX you don't need to save it.

Comment: Exactly it is Irvine's book, but shame on my chinese version(typographic error). Your answer is quite clear.